# different php.ini settings for various virtualhost (php-fpm)

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

I searched allot here on serverFault and found this solution...

Including this in virtual host should work:

```
  php_admin_flag register_argc_argv = On
  php_value max_execution_time = 1000
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime = 15000
  php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc = on
```

But than it dawned me, I'm not using mod_php at all. I have php-fpm installed. And I really cannot find any information if my method will work, or if there is an alternative way...

So, what do I do if I've php-fpm and would like to have different settings for virtualhost?

S.

Comment: Why would you *ever* want magic quotes? Those are evil.

Comment: @NathanC I know, but script author was even rude enough to tell me: "Yes all requirements are needed, that is why they are requirements."

Comment: If only it were possible to fire that script author.

Comment: @NathanC yeah, I hate snobby developers :) only if I had time, I would develop it myself :S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On php-fpm, you usually set this in the fpm pool of the domain. The pools are included from php-fpm's main conf-file, which is located on my server at `/etc/php/fpm-php5.3/php-fpm.conf`:

```
...

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

include=/var/www/*/conf/fpm-pool.conf
```

In the fpm-pool-config, you can set `php_admin_flag` and `php_admin_value` like this:

```
...

;   php_value/php_flag             - you can set classic ini defines which can
;                                    be overwritten from PHP call 'ini_set'. 
;   php_admin_value/php_admin_flag - these directives won't be overwritten by
;                                     PHP call 'ini_set'
php_flag[display_errors]            = on
php_admin_value[error_log]          = /var/www/cloud/logs/php_err.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors]          = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit]       = 1024M
#php_value[max_execution_time]       = 30
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 4G
php_admin_value[post_max_size]      = 4.2G
php_admin_value[max_input_time]     = 3600
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 3600
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a RAM-hungry server and wanted to avoid configuring multiple pools for each of the low-traffic sites I was running. I also didn't like the security concerns of directory-based .user.ini’s, so I implemented a different solution using php.ini "sections":

http://php.net/ini.sections

You can define sections of php.ini (in my case, /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini) that are either path, or host, specific. At the bottom, I have:

```
[HOST=host1.example.com]
auto_prepend_file = '/var/www/something'

[HOST=host2.example.net]
upload_max_filesize = 5M
```

I read elsewhere that if you use the host method, you must use the specific value defined in ServerName in the VirtualHost config, not any of the aliases.

P.S. This was all done on Debian Jessie 8.4

Comment: Currently, [PATH=] and [HOST=] sections only work under CGI/FastCGI

Answer (score 1):

You can include these flags in an .htaccess file under each virtual host that you want these settings. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: Isn't this possible only with mod_php? I've php-fpm installed.

Comment: From what I've read, this is the method to accomplish it with php-fpm. mod_php allows the directives to be in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

**For nginx use this solution:**

Since `PHP 5.3.3` you can use this command in your `nginx`-vhost-file.

Example for setting the `maxlifetime` of sessions:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...

        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "session.gc_maxlifetime=604800";
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "session.cookie_lifetime=604800";
    }
}
```